# Why am i getting error on using any `nx` commands

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

Command used : `nx`

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@nrwl/workspace/src/command-line/supported-nx-commands'
Require stack:
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js
- /Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-global.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.initLocal (/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js:12:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js:12:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-local.js',
    '/Users/shawntony/projects/ktp-web/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/init-global.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/bin/nx.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just had this issue myself. Fixed it by deleting all my node_modules, verifying npm cache, updating my global @nrwl-cli, and reinstalling. In short:

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npm install -g @nrwl/cli`
4. `npm install`

Not sure of what did the trick, but I suppose it some kind of inconsistency in some @nrwl module version in the project or in the cache.

Comment: The first step isn't running on my windows engine, but i switched to the app folder and deleted the node_module with "rmdir /q/s node_modules"

Comment: if npm install works with errors

use:   npm i  --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add a quick point to FYE answer. If you are running these commands on the windows, `-rf` tag might not work for you, use `-r` instead

```
rm -r node_modules
```

It will recursively remove all the files.

If there are some hidden files as well , you can use -Force tag like following -

```
rm -r -fo node_modules
```