# How to run Nx serve on Angular in debug mode on VSCode?

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode-debugger

I must run my Angular Nx project in the VSCode debugger with `yarn`.

`yarn start` will just run the `nx serve` command and works as intended when launched from a shell.

My VSCode debugger just run the exact same `yarn start` command. Before the migration from Angular-client (`ng`), it was working like a charm.

Now, I keep getting this error:

```
*  Executing task: yarn run start 

yarn run v1.22.19
$ nx serve
/path/to/project/node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js:132
    globalThis.GLOBAL_NX_VERSION ??= GLOBAL_NX_VERSION;
                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

 *  The terminal process "/usr/bin/zsh '-c', 'yarn run start'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

*Additional sub issue*:
When I ran the debug mode (at the time it was running), it always went through the `node_modules` code while I had put the node modules in my `skipFiles` list.

Here is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Firefox: start",
      "preLaunchTask": "Angular Client: yarn start",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "type": "firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack:///src",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        }
      ],
      "skipFiles": [
        // FIXME: Does not work, debugger still goes through node_packages code
        "${workspaceFolder}/<node_internals>/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my `tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Angular Client: yarn start",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "yarn",
      "args": ["start"],  // FIXME: Does not work with Nx in VSCode
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "source": "ts",
        "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
        "fileLocation": "relative",
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this link for information about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643563/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-using-any-nx-commands

Comment: I already did that. Deleting `node_modules` each time is not viable. Also, this doesn't always solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `??=` operator was added in NodeJS v15.

And if you are getting this error it means that you are running node v14 or older.

Since `nx` is using `??=` that must mean that they decided to drop support for v14 and older.

You'll find that a lot of other modules have also dropped support for v14 and they will likely stop supporting v16 soon as well.

My advice would be to see if your project can run with node v18 or at least v16 and if it can't then to try updating the project.

If you really have to stay on node v14 then you'll have no choice other than to install an older version of `nx` (and probably other modules).

---

As for skipping files while debugging, have you tried this?

```json
  "skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js"
  ]
```

Comment: I'm using Node 18.15.0. I don't know which version VS Code debugger is using, but I only have this one installed so, unless the debugger uses its own Node, I'm on Node 18.

Comment: VS Code allows you to specify node version when running the debugger. That's likely what's causing your problem. Check if you have set `runtimeVersion` in your `launch.json` under the `.vscode` folder.

Comment: To be sure you can confirm the actual version of node by replacing your current script with one that simply logs the version like this `console.log(process.version)`